# Problem with getting Rails ENV variable in yml file, it give float instead of whole string

Tags: ruby, yaml

I have an Environment variable in me env file that is

```
SOME_CLIENT_ID= 574536488180.574908975999
```

and I included this in my `secrects.yml` file like this

```
some_client_id: <%= ENV['SOME_CLIENT_ID'] %>
```

and when I'm getting this in my `.rb` and `rails console` with `Rails.application.secrets.some_client_id` this give me `574536488180.575` instead of `574536488180.574908975999` and `ENV['SOME_CLIENT_ID']` Gives accurate value. `Rails.application.secrets.some_client_id` seems like it give me round of value but I needed as I entered orignal value.

how can I tackle this issue? please help me.
thanks

Comment: _Sidenote:_ this issue has nothing to do with _Rails_, tags updated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That’s the issue with YAML parser being too smart. Tell them it’s a string:

```
- some_client_id: <%= ENV['SOME_CLIENT_ID'] %>
+ some_client_id: "<%= ENV['SOME_CLIENT_ID'] %>"
```

Answer (score 1):

Ruby is interpreting the value in your SOME_CLIENT_ID variable as a float. If the value is not a floating point number, I recommend you set it as a string in your secrets file:

```
some_client_id: '<%= ENV['SOME_CLIENT_ID'] %>'
```

Comment: I see. I think the interpolation in the secrets file is still interpreting it as a float.

Comment: Yeah :( is there any solution that will help to cope this serious issue??

Comment: It makes zero sense to try to fix an issue on the env var level. Environment vars are _all strings_ already.

Comment: @AlekseiMatiushkin you are right, I suggested the fix in the wrong file. I've edited my answer.